# How to efficiently sort a column from two tables?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

In our app, we have assignments. We create this by unioning two other tables with a `due_date` column: `checklists` and `tasks`. We want to order `assignments` by the `due_dates`. Right now, we are doing something like this:

```
select * from (
  select a.type, t.id, t.due_date from assignments a
    inner join tasks t on t.id = a.task_id
  where a.type = 'Task' and a.user_id = 'X'
  union
  select a.type, c.id, c.due_date from assignments a
    inner join checklists c on c.id = a.checklist_id
  where a.type = 'Checklist' and a.user_id 'X'
)
order by due_date desc
limit 20
```

Obviously, this goes very slow because it needs to generate all the task and checklist assignments (which can be in the 100000s) and then sort them and grab the top 20.

Adding an index doesn't help because the due_date field is in separate tables.

We looked at table inheritance, but it seems to just be syntactic sugar for unions, so doesn't really help.

Also, because there are so many assignments, it seems like materialized views wouldn't help because they'd have to be refreshed every 100ms or so.

What is a good way to optimize this type of query?

Comment: can you paste the result of `\d assignments` and also can you follow up with an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`

Comment: We are in the same team with Cameron. Here is the `explain analyse ...` with the real relationships:  https://gist.github.com/ShurikAg/175444dd2634642da9f0afb0ab384191

Comment: Here is `\d assignments`: https://gist.github.com/ShurikAg/64e23be9f92b0b5711e212745177bf89

Comment: It woul dhelp if you shows the `CREATE TABLE` statements (and indexes) for all tables and the execution plan.

Comment: Why isn't `organization_id` used in the joins? It seems to be part of the FKs.

Answer (score 2):

You might get improved performance by doing the following:

- Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` (as suggested by Thangamani Eraniyan).
- Make sure both tables have an index on `due_date` (or with `due_date` as the first column, if there are more columns indexed).
- Use the `ORDER BY` and the `LIMIT 20` on the separate queries of the two tables, as well as on the final combined result. The individual queries do have to be subqueries; otherwise, we can't use `ORDER BY` on them.

The principle is to limit the number of records that need to be looked at in both individual tables. With an index on `due_date` in both tables, it should be able to find the most recent records quickly. We know that the top 20 records from both tables can't include more than 20 `tasks` or more than 20 `checklists`, so if we just grab the top 20 from *each* table, we've definitely got the top 20 form the *combined* tables. The final `ORDER BY ... LIMIT` simply drops out rows 21-40.

Try this; I tested the same basic query via [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ebK1Gyib6Frs84gG5fQpV/0), and it worked (so, barring any cut-and-paste errors combining that with your actual query, this should work as well).

```
SELECT type, id, due_date FROM 
   (SELECT a.type, t.id, t.due_date
      FROM assignments a
             INNER JOIN tasks t on t.id = a.task_id
     ORDER BY t.due_date ASC
     LIMIT 20) sq1
UNION ALL
SELECT type, id, due_date FROM 
   (SELECT a.type, c.id, c.due_date
      FROM assignments a
             INNER JOIN checklists c on c.id = a.checklist_id
     ORDER BY c.due_date DESC
     LIMIT 20) sq2
 ORDER BY due_date ASC
 LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: I think Pg is smart enough to handle the `LIMIT`s, this may actually slow it down. But, we'd have to see on the ops dataset.

Comment: The issue with setting a limit on a subqueries, is that there is no way to figure out the offset for deeper pages.

Comment: @ShurikAgulyansky the question doesn't say anything about offsets. But you can use this method (although it may be slow for high offsets). If one want `OFFSET x LIMIT n`, they can so `LIMIT x+n` in the subqueries and `OFFSET x LIMIT n` in the main query.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ This way of offset calculating is not going to work, because after the first page was retrieved you don't know where is was retrieved from.

Comment: @ShurikAgulyansky I don't follow. What do you mean with *"where it was retrieved"*?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I mean, once you got your first page, how do you know which one of th union parts it came from, so you can set the offset for the next page

Comment: I just described how, in my comment above. If you want page 2, you get all the rows (for pages 1 and 2) in the subqueries, from both tables, and you do the offset, limit in the main query. It's not going to be efficient for big offset, but big offsets are hard anyway.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Well, that was the whole point of this question, to address the bid sets.

Comment: the question does not mention offsets at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here two things that can be help to improve:

- Instead of `UNION`, you can use `UNION ALL` (since you are using different criteria, always record will be different from each other) to avoid unique comparison from Oracle side.
- Also, you don't need the subquery to do `ORDER BY`; it automatically applies to the results of the `UNION ALL` (or `UNION`).

I hope it may help you.

```
select a.type, t.id, t.due_date from assignments a
    inner join tasks t on t.id = a.task_id
  where a.type = 'Task' and a.user_id = 'X'
  union all
  select a.type, c.id, c.due_date from assignments a
    inner join checklists c on c.id = a.checklist_id
  where a.type = 'Checklist' and a.user_id = 'X'
  order BY  due_date desc
limit 20
```